# VBA - Copy all corresponding values from two ranges

Tags: vba, copy, compare

I want to compare two ranges and then copy those cells from column C that have a value in common with column O. Right now, it copies only the last cell in common, not all. But if I color the cells red, all cells in common turn red. What do I do wrong?

```
Sub CompareRangesOrigineel()
Dim WorkRng1 As Range, WorkRng2 As Range, Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range
Set WorkRng1 = Range("C5:C31")
Set WorkRng2 = Range("O3:O30")
For Each Rng1 In WorkRng1
    rng1Value = Rng1.Value
    For Each Rng2 In WorkRng2
        If rng1Value = Rng2.Value And Not IsEmpty(Rng1) Then
            Rng1.Copy
            Rng1.Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(500, 0, 0)
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: After Rng1.Copy you need to provide a destination to paste the copied cell e.g. Rng1.Copy Rng2

Comment: But it is still copying only the last cell in common. There are multiple cells in WorkRng1 that I want to copy. Right now, at Rng1.Copy, its is only copying the last cell. How can I fix that all duplicate cells can be copied?